# How to calculate number of tuples in a page?

Tags: storage

I have been working on this particular question since yesterday and I can seem to figure out how to solve it:

*Assume that your files are organised based on slotted page array which contains a header (8B) and slot references of 2B each. Insert in the text below the number of tuples that you believe can fit completely in a 10KB slotted page array for the relation of Publisher which defines two fields: PUB_NAME: char(22) and website:char(32).*

I don't know if I'm missing something, however I originally thought that you need to add 8B + 2B + 2B + 22B + 32B = 66B and then divide it 10000B/66B = 151,515152 where I round it to 151B.

That is not the right answer, neither is 152 if I round it up.

I would appreciate it if I could get some guideance/help on how to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First why store the refernce twice. It saved 2 bytes.
Second 10 KB is Not 10000, it is 10240.

So the result should be 160 flat

64B of meta data (8 + 2 + 22 + 32).